# How to add object to WSDL service system.array

Tags: c#, arrays, web-services, wsdl

I am currently working with a WSDL that has a method to save invoices. I have been able to modify existing invoices, but haven't figured out how to save new ones. Since the array size is immutable, I am unable to add objects to the array that is retrieved. How should I go about saving new invoices, and is there a way to add them into the array? The WSDL doesn't have another method for saving individual invoices.

```
Invoices.InvoiceOrder[] po = _service.GetInvoices(_params, invoiceReturnProperties, rowReturnProperties);

//test import of new po
Invoices.InvoiceOrder newInvoice = new Invoices.InvoiceOrder();

//specify individual properties that need to be set

newInvoice.OrderId = 28;
newInvoice.CustomerName = "James Bond";
newInvoice.CustomerId = 28;

po[po.Length] = newInvoice; //not sure how to accomplish this

//save invoices
_service.SaveInvoices(po);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you say the array is immutable? Does the 2nd to last line throw an error?

If it is in fact immutable, you can use `Array.Clone` to copy the existing array and pass that.  Alternatively, if the service is only expecting new/edited invoices to be passed to the `SaveInvoices` operation (which makes more sense to me), you can do this:

```
//save invoices
_service.SaveInvoices(new [] {p});
```

Read about the Array.Clone method:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clone.aspx

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. It was throwing an out of bounds exception with the 2nd to last line.